# Difference between "spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead" and "spark.memory.offHeap.size"

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I am running spark on yarn. I don't understand what is the difference between the following settings `spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead` and `spark.memory.offHeap.size`. Both seem to be settings for allocating off-heap memory to spark executor. Which one should I use? Also what is the recommended setting for executor offheap memory?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 20):

**TL;DR:** For Spark 1.x and 2.x, Total Off-Heap Memory = `spark.executor.memoryOverhead` (spark.offHeap.size included within)
For Spark 3.x, Total Off-Heap Memory = `spark.executor.memoryOverhead` + `spark.offHeap.size` (credit from [this page](https://medium.com/walmartglobaltech/decoding-memory-in-spark-parameters-that-are-often-confused-c11be7488a24))

Detailed explanation:

`spark.executor.memoryOverhead` is used by resource management like YARN, whereas `spark.memory.offHeap.size` is used by Spark core (memory manager). The relationship a bit different depending on the version.

**Spark 2.4.5 and before:**

`spark.executor.memoryOverhead` should include `spark.memory.offHeap.size`. This means that if you specify `offHeap.size`, you need to manually add this portion to `memoryOverhead` for YARN. As you can see from the code below from [YarnAllocator.scala](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.4.5/resource-managers/yarn/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/deploy/yarn/YarnAllocator.scala), when YARN request resource, it does not know anything about `offHeap.size`:

```
private[yarn] val resource = Resource.newInstance(
    executorMemory + memoryOverhead + pysparkWorkerMemory,
    executorCores)
```

**However, the behavior is changed in Spark 3.0:**

`spark.executor.memoryOverhead` does not include `spark.memory.offHeap.size` anymore. YARN will include `offHeap.size` for you when requesting resources. From the new [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0-preview2/configuration.html):

> Note: Additional memory includes PySpark executor memory (when spark.executor.pyspark.memory is not configured) and memory used by other non-executor processes running in the same container. The maximum memory size of container to running executor is determined by the sum of spark.executor.memoryOverhead, spark.executor.memory, spark.memory.offHeap.size and spark.executor.pyspark.memory.

And from the [code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/6550d0d5283efdbbd838f3aeaf0476c7f52a0fb1/resource-managers/yarn/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/deploy/yarn/YarnAllocator.scala) you can also tell:

```
private[yarn] val resource: Resource = {
    val resource = Resource.newInstance(
      executorMemory + executorOffHeapMemory + memoryOverhead + pysparkWorkerMemory, executorCores)
    ResourceRequestHelper.setResourceRequests(executorResourceRequests, resource)
    logDebug(s"Created resource capability: $resource")
    resource
  }
```

For more details of this change you can refer to [this Pull Request](https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/25309).

For your second question, what is the recommended setting for executor offheap memory? It depends on your application and you need some testing. I found [this](https://www.waitingforcode.com/apache-spark/apache-spark-off-heap-memory/read) page helpful to explain it further:

> Off-heap memory is a great way to reduce GC pauses because it's not in the GC's scope. However, it brings an overhead of serialization and deserialization. The latter in its turn makes that the off-heap data can be sometimes put onto heap memory and hence be exposed to GC. Also, the new data format brought by Project Tungsten (array of bytes) helps to reduce the GC overhead. These 2 reasons make that the use of off-heap memory in Apache Spark applications should be carefully planned and, especially, tested.

BTW, `spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead` is deprecated and changed to `spark.executor.memoryOverhead`, which is common for YARN and Kubernetes.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on the differences between these 2 parameters?

Answer (score 0):

1. `spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead` is used in StaticMemoryManager. This is used in older Spark Version like 1.2.

> The amount of off heap memory (in megabytes) to be allocated per executor. This is memory that accounts for things like VM overheads, interned strings, other native overheads, etc. This tends to grow with the executor size (typically 6-10%).

You can find this in older Spark docs,like Spark1.2 docs:

```
https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/running-on-yarn.html
```

---

2. `spark.memory.offHeap.size` is used in UnifiedMemoryManager, which is used by default after version 1.6

> The absolute amount of memory in bytes which can be used for off-heap allocation. This setting has no impact on heap memory usage, so if your executors' total memory consumption must fit within some hard limit then be sure to shrink your JVM heap size accordingly. This must be set to a positive value when spark.memory.offHeap.enabled=true.

You can find this in lates Spark docs,like Spark2.4 docs:

```
https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.4/configuration.html
```